# G210M Screen brightness control issue

Tags: brightness

I have a Sony VAIO VPCCW15FG laptop with NVIDIA G210M graphics card. I can't adjust the screen brightness! If I use the Fn shortcuts the brightness notification shows-up and there the brightness changes the level but nothing happens.

I was able to adjust the brightness level in [ZorinOS](http://zorin-os.com/).  But nothing happens when I changed the bright level, then brightness level changes radically with each step in the last stages.

Answer (score 0):

I am having  Sony Vaio ( installing Ubuntu 12.04 ) and my problem solved following this link

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11910629#post11910629

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.